# How to change the login type in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: gnome, 13.04, login-screen

Whenever I change to Gnome Fallback, Ubuntu changes it right back to the default Ubuntu, any help?
Oh, and this is on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: What desktop environment are you running?  Can you add an image?  If not upload it, add the link, and I will add it for you